# how to add ability to upload multiple images for a product in zen cart?

Tags: zen-cart

How can I add the ability of uploading multiple images for a product from the admin side.

I have search for it and found that upload an image from the admin side and then for adding additional images you should upload it through ftp.

But I did not want this. I want that admin should be able to upload multiple images from the admin panel for a single product.

How will I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version of Zen Cart are you using? If you're using 1.3.x then you should install [Image Handler](http://www.zen-cart.com/index.php?main_page=product_contrib_info&products_id=1910) (found in the official Free Add Ons section). Unfortunately, IH is currently not compatible with 1.5.0 admin section (although the frontend functionality will work). From what I know, there's currently nothing you can do with 1.5.0 except code the funcionality yourself.

Answer (score 0):

There is now an updated Image Handler available for v1.5.0.  http://www.zen-cart.com/plugins

There are other addons such as "Image Manager" which allow for additional admin-side image management.